# Java Image Editing Fill Area not working

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a part of my image editing program that fills any area of the image where it is (a) the same color as the selected coordinate, and (b) adjacent to a spot that is valid for replacing, with the attribute `this.color`. Essentially, the method of filling that MS Paint uses. Here is the method:

```
public void branchFrom(int x, int y) {
        int color = this.color.getRGB(); // Color to fill in the area
        Color original = new Color(this.image.getRGB(x, y)); // Color of the selected coordinate
        this.replace(x, y, color); // First replaces the selected spot with the indicated color
        // Next, it checks all spots joined to itself by an edge. If it is invalid for filling, it continues to the next adjacency. Else, it fills the area and continues branching from there, until all spots are filled
        this.replaceSecondaryOnCondition(x + 1, y, clr -> {
            if (clr.equals(original)) {
                this.branchFromSecondary(x + 1, y);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.replaceSecondaryOnCondition(x - 1, y, clr -> {
            if (clr.equals(original)) {
                this.branchFromSecondary(x - 1, y);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.replaceSecondaryOnCondition(x, y + 1, clr -> {
            if (clr.equals(original)) {
                this.branchFromSecondary(x, y + 1);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.replaceSecondaryOnCondition(x, y - 1, clr -> {
            if (clr.equals(original)) {
                this.branchFromSecondary(x, y - 1);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works perfectly well, except when `original` is transparent. Why is this, and how do I fix the issue?

**EDIT:** It works when `this.color` is transparent. It seems to fail whenever `original` is not 100% opaque (e.g. has an `alpha` value of `< 255`)

Comment: What is the type / class for `this.image`?

Comment: `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Color(int rgb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)) constructor you are using "creates an opaque sRGB color ..."  The [`Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20boolean)) constructor will create a new `Color` with transparency.
Try changing this line:

```
Color original = new Color(this.image.getRGB(x, y));
```

To this:

```
Color original = new Color(this.image.getRGB(x, y), true);
```

Note: if you using the `Color(int rgb)` constructor in other related code (such as your `replace` method, you'll probably need to change those as well.

Comment: Thank You! I always have assumed that the `Color(int)` constructor used alpha. Thanks a lot!